# Connect to DSL connection (PPPoE) via WiFi in Mint?

Tags: linux-mint, wifi, vpn

There is a private LAN in our office and every one using the internet must define a PPPoE-connection to connect to the internet. I created a DSL (PPPoE) connection in Linux Mint. When I connect to the LAN via the Ethernet cable, every thing is fine and PPPoE connection connects to the internet.

But when I remove the Ethernet cable and connect over WiFi the DSL connection which was defined before becomes disabled, so I can't connect to the internet.

How should I define the DSL connection to connect through the WiFi connection?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tNlHfM1HgHQ